# Como obter valores para popular um dropdown dinamicamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, dropdown

Estou desenvolvendo em .NET MVC e na minha aplicação, possuo um formulário que cadastra pessoas via Ajax. Esse elemento cadastrado devera aparecer em uma lista *dropdown*, ele deverá aparecer dinamicamente sem atualizar a página, alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer isso?

Não consigo obter os nomes na minha lista *dropdown* sem atualizar! Teria alguma forma de quando clicar no *dropdown* ele mostrasse os itens inseridos no campo anterior?

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da complexidade da sua tela eu sugiro utilizar Javascript para tal, porém a seguir fiz um exemplo com uma alternativa diferente, para lhe dar algumas ideias, espero que lhe ajude:

Adicione o arquivo ao seu *header*:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

Código do controle:

```
public static class DropDownDB
{
   public static List<string> Nomes = new List<string> { "Nome 1", "Nome 2", "Nome 3" };
}

public class DropDownController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(string nome)
   {
      DropDownDB.Nomes.Add(nome);
      return MeuDrop();
   }

   public ActionResult MeuDrop()
   {
      return PartialView("MeuDrop", new SelectList(DropDownDB.Nomes));
   }
}
```

Da *View*:

```
@model string

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "replaceDiv", OnSuccess = "$('.text').val('');" }))
{
   <input type="text" name="nome" />
   <button type="submit">Adicionar</button>
}
<div id="replaceDiv">
   @Html.Action("MeuDrop")
</div>
```

E da *Partial View* criada para o *dropdown*:

```
@model SelectList
@DateTime.Now
@Html.DropDownList("drop", Model)
```